# Finding frequency of rows in a dataframe that meet conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the form of:

```
Date    Time  station   num_bikes  
1     3.02    Girwood   0                        
2     4.10    Fraser    0                           
3     10.10   Carslile  0
4     10.10   Girwood   5
5     7.46    Fraser    0
6     3.02    Girwood   0
```

I want to know the time and the number of occurances that the number of bikes is zero.
In the form of:

```
Time  Station Occurrences 
3.02   Girwood   2   
9.05   Girwood   1  
4.10   Fraser    1                                  
7.46   Fraser    1  
10.10  Carslile  1
```

Comment: I would like all times that the number of bikes equal to zero occurs at.

Comment: does that clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter to only those rows that satisfy your condition and then `groupby` + `size`. Using a `NamedAgg` cleans up the syntax a bit. You can take the `size` of any column, so I arbitrarily chose `'Time'`.

```
(df[df.num_bikes.eq(0)]
   .groupby(['Time', 'station'])
   .agg(occurences=('Time', 'size'))
   .reset_index())

    Time   station  occurences
0   3.02   Girwood           2
1   4.10    Fraser           1
2   7.46    Fraser           1
3  10.10  Carslile           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something different using `pd.crosstab` with direct column name `Occurences`

```
df1 = df.loc[df.num_bikes.eq(0)]

pd.crosstab([df1.Time, df1.station], 'Occurrences').reset_index()

Out[996]:
    Time   station  Occurrences
0   3.02   Girwood            2
1   4.10    Fraser            1
2   7.46    Fraser            1
3  10.10  Carslile            1
```